# Set laravel job's timeout based on some config

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

To set Laravel job's `$timeout` value we can use this code

```
public $timeout = 120;
```

Is there a way to set this value dynamically (via a method)? something like this

```
public function timeout(): int
{
    return config('general.some_config');
}
```

The above code does not seem to have any effect on the job's timeout value.

Comment: Setting the timeout value inside the `__constructor` method works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it by constructor in like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->timeout = config('general.some_config');
}
```