# Set Laravel's queue timeout dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

I've coded Laravel from 6 years ago and now I have to deal with a situation where the user can set the queue timeout because there is long-running process that needs to fail according to the user's timeout.

```php
class MyQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $userTimeout;

  public function __construct($userTimeout)
  {
    $this->userTimeout = $userTimeout;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    MyService::compute(); // very heavy process (hypotethically)
    
    // the queue needs to fail if the above computation exceeds the $userTimeout. 
    // this following code won't run logically before the above code finishes
    if ($userTimeoutIsReached) {
      $this->fail();
    }

  }
}
```

I need to be able to do this from Controller

```php
MyQueue::dispatch(request()->userTimeout);
```

Need some thoughts from you guys to get the bottom of this. I'm stuck. Please help

Comment: [Set laravel job's timeout based on some config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187256/set-laravel-jobs-timeout-based-on-some-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel already has timeout property on their job class.

just change `userTimeout` to `timeout` as [their documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#timeout)

And also if you want to mark as fail after time out just add `failOnTimeout` property also.

So the final code should be like:

```
class MyQueue implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  public $timeout = 120; //default timeout
  public $failOnTimeout = true;



  public function __construct($userTimeout)
  {
    $this->timeout = $userTimeout;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    MyService::compute(); // very heavy process (hypotethically)

  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. I tried to simulate it with `while(true) { $i++; dump($i); sleep(1); } ` , it keeps running, doesn't get failed

Comment: @mending3 I tested and it worked 100%. what laravel version you use? and also what connection?

Comment: do you have example github repo of it? Laravel 9, `DATABASE` queue connection

Comment: I used the code that I wrote on my answer, and it's 100% worked.
The possibility you not worked is  `request()->userTimeout` returned 0, so it unimited. Or another possibility is you used `queue:listen` command instead of `queue:work`. You should use `queue:work` for queue worker.

Comment: ah yea. this works. I'm running this on docker and I didn't install pcntl extension on the supervisor service on docker-compose.yml. thanks